# Set nginx root based on existance of another directory

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, wildcard-subdomain

I'm building a system which uses dynamic DNS for user accounts, so you register for a sub domain.

I have a few server directives in place to catch things like api. and www. and other special cases, and I have a directive which reads the wildcard domain name and uses it to set a domain specific assets location.

```
server {
  server_name "~^(?<domain>[a-z0-9]+)\.example\.com$";
  root /sites/core;
  location /assets {
    alias /site-assets/$domain;
  }
}
```

What I want to do is check for the existence of the assets directory and present, on the same domain, a different site.

To clarify, if the assets directory in the example above exists, serve one set of files, otherwise, serve another. Since the site I want to serve won't be IN the directory in question, I can't use try_files or anything like that.

I read all the horror stories about using the if directive but I think I need something like

```
if (-d /site-assets/$domain) {
  ... Do something
}
```

Then change the root, but that doesn't work.

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Comment: Please explain more what that does actually mean *check for the existence of the assets directory and present, on the same domain, the joining page.*?

Comment: That line is quite specific to my build but not this problem. Essentially I'm looking to check for the existence of a specific directory on the server and if it exists, serve on set of content, otherwise, serve another set. But not content from that specific directory, so try_files is not suitable.

Comment: It seems that *a directory existence* is the part of business logic because Nginx will serve specific content based on that rule (true/false). If possible take logic out of web server configuration until you need Lua (separate module) or Perl (built-in module) to keep business logic within Nginx configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. My intention here is to serve up an Angular app, so as far as Nginx is concerned it's all static content. Rather than passing the request to PHP, or Python, or whatever, is Nginx could do it, there would be less server overhead.

Answer (score 2):

OK. I figured this out. If there's a problem with it, let me know.

I have the following in a server directive

```
server {
    server_name "~^(?<domain>[a-z0-9]+)\.example\.com$";
    set $site core;
    if (!-d /path/to/assets/$domain) {
        set $site join;
    }

    root /path/to/sites/$site;
}
```

If the assets directory for the given domain name does NOT exist, then I can serve up a joining page for my site, which can pick up the domain name and allow the user to register. If it does exist, then serve up the main app.

This seems to me like a simple use of the if directive so shouldn't get me in too much trouble.